# How to use insert statement instead of this merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I have merge statement in script, but i want to know how I can write insert statement for the script. Let me explain in code
In the below code I have 2 conditions one not matched by target and @column=1

If i want to write a insert statement for this what I have to write

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND (@abcd = 1)
        THEN
            INSERT (columns)
            VALUES (columns)
```

Comment: Did you tried to look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-merge-to-perform-update-and-insert-operations-on-a-target-table-by-using-a-derived-source-table)?

Comment: What is your merged based on ? How are you determining when to insert/not insert?

Comment: when to insert, like I have two conditions here 

If there is no condition I can write Insert into tableA Select cols from TableB b where not exists( select col from TableA a where a.id=b.id)   here I have two conditions when not matched by target and @abcd=1

Comment: sample data and expected result will help us understand your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify your demand please ?

I did understand all but i think you whant to insert in TAB_A if id not exist in TAB_B and if param @abcd = 1 so for this the relevant query was :

```
INSERT INTO TAB_A(IdCol, SomeCol)
SELECT IdCol, SomeCol
FROM TAB_K 
WHERE IdCol NOT IN (SELECT IdCol FROM TAB_B) AND @abcd = 1
```

OR if you didn't have TAB_K:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_A(IdCol, SomeCol)
SELECT '1','SomeColToAdd'
WHERE '1' NOT IN (SELECT IdCol FROM TAB_B) AND @abcd = 1
```